# Which is better to use Lombok's @NonNull or Objects.requireNonNull?

Tags: java, lombok

As far as I know both check the non null at runtime. Is there any preference or industry standard to use perticular thing?

Comment: One opinion among the many that this is calling for: use standard libraries until they become insufficient.

Comment: "*As far as I know both check the non null at runtime*" -- your understanding is flawed.  *No* annotation has any runtime behavior of its own.  If you happen to process your annotation-bearing code with the right annotation processor at compile time then it might *insert code* for runtime null checks for variables annotated with `@NonNull`, but that's quite a different thing.